# What is actually happening on line 4 when returning the dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to understand this code, but I am confused on what's going on with the memoization part of my code. Line 3 has `return fibstorage[x]`, but what does this actually do? I know that above it's checking if `x` is inside the dictionary, but afterward what is this really returning? And why is `x` in brackets after `fibstorage` is called?

```
fibstorage = {}
def fib(x):
    if x in fibstorage:
        return fibstorage[x]
    elif x == 1:
        value = 1
    elif x == 2:
        value = 1
    elif x > 2:
        value = fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
    fibstorage[x] = value
    return value
whatever = 100
for i in range(1, whatever + 1):
    print("fib({})".format(i), fib(i))
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fibstorage is a dictionary. You can imagine them to be a little like a list you reference with a value rather than a position.
Such as

```
x = {'Hello': 'world',
     'foo': 'bar'
     8: 'eight'}
print(x['Hello']) #would print world
print(x['foo']) #would print bar
print(x[8]) #would print eight
```

It appears to be a caching method so if x has already been computed it doesn't have to be computed again.

If you have further questions feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That definitely helps, I have one more question here, what is the point of the return function there?

Comment: @Ballum the return will be used to return the number that has been calculated. This type of function is a little complex i suggest you look up a "recursive fibonacci"